# Java - extendes from JPanel adding new panels inside

Tags: java, swing

I'm using a `JPanel` and tring to create a two new panels programatically inside this `JPanel`

```
public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainWindow
     */
    private javax.swing.JPanel jviewer;

    public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
        jviewer = new ImageRender(123);
    }
}
```

For that reason, I have the next extension:

```
public class ImageRender extends JPanel {

    JPanel mainViewer = new JPanel();
    JPanel galleryViewer = new JPanel();

    public ImageRender(Integer itemnum) {


        setLayout(null);

        mainViewer = new JPanel();
        mainViewer.setBackground(Color.red);
        mainViewer.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);

        galleryViewer = new JPanel();
        galleryViewer.setBackground(Color.green);
        galleryViewer.setBounds(210, 0, 50, 200);

        this.add(mainViewer);
        add(galleryViewer);
        mainViewer.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Se ha finalizado esta tarea");

    }

}
```

But, at this point, is not displaying any of the JPanel created in the `ImageRender.java` also any errors.

Someone has an idea about how to fix my implementation?

Comment: You create an ImageRender, but you do nothing with it (like... adding it to the frame). Also, don't use the null layout. Use a layout manager.

Comment: @JBNizet with the extends, can I call directly the add(galleryViewer); , right? I mean, doing reference to the parent object

Comment: You're already doing it, and it compiles fine, right? So yes. Not sure what that has to do with your question and with my comment though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason of that is that you create an `ImageRender` instance, but it is never being added to the JFrame. Use `add` method in order to achieve that. Also do not use `setLayout(null)` and `setBounds`. [Use a layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead. Components will be validated automatically, plus you have a resizable window.

The fact `ImageRender extends JPanel` means that an `ImageRender` object is also a JPanel, hence it can be added to the frame. (Already mentioned in comments)

Take a look at an example (assume `ImageRenderer` class is in another file):

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(new ImageRenderer()); //Create and add a new ImageRendere panel
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Test().setVisible(true));
    }

    private static class ImageRenderer extends JPanel {
        public ImageRenderer() {
            super(new GridLayout());

            JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            leftPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
            add(leftPanel);

            JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            rightPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
            add(rightPanel);
        }
    }
}
```